# Background of Listview Different on Devices

Tags: android, listadapter

I have a TextView that I am populating with an adapter via android functionality.  Here is the textView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Here is the code to populate:

```
mList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        if (mLocNames != null) {
            if (mLocNames.size() != 0) {
                mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_widget_list_item, mLocNames);
                mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        }
```

The background takes on the color of the parent view on most devices, but on Wildfire HTC, it does not.

Here is Samsung Galaxy:

[image]

Here is Wildfire HTC:

[image]

EDIT:  Wildfire HTC with TextView background set to blue:
[image]

When I press on list item, I can see the location due to highlight.  I want the entire screen to be blue like it is on Samsung Galaxy and many other devices.  Any idea what is going on?

EDIT:  Including XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_lines"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_lines_20_tiled"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_location_ll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.accuweather.android.views.SimpleSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/or_use"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/use_gps"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/first_launch_location_selector"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/my_current_location"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/descrip_enable_location"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_location_ll" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#88808080" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can set the background color of your textview (listitem) to that blue

Comment: I can do that, correct, but it only makes blue the list items, not all the additional content area like the Samsung Galaxy image.

Comment: You can set the background of your parent viewgroup to blue, this will solve the additional content area problem